# Facebook like and share button config — problems with fb:admins and fb:app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-share

We have a simple blog website and a Facebook page. I need to add a like and share button to the website article pages so people can like and share them with their friends.

I have all the `og:` set correctly and the `article:author` points to my Facebook page, but the debug page is telling me that I need to set `fb:admins` and `fb:app_id` in order for it to properly display.

It is simply not liking when I set the `fb:app_id` to my page ID, so it seems I need to create a Facebook app, but why!? Surely I don't need to create an app and have it submitted for review for my simple use case do I?

If that is the case then there seems to be no way to set my page ID in the meta tags, which seems strange.

When I set it to the page ID I get the following error:

```
Object at URL '...' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '[page_id]' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.
```

Also, it seems to only like Facebook user IDs for `fb:admins` (I tried page ID here and it didn't like it). Why do I need to set this value? Can't it get the admin accounts from my page's admins? Why do I have to manage this list of users if it's already managed in Facebook?

I hope someone can clear these issues up for me as I'm rather confused!

I basically need it all fully linked up so any likes and shares are attributed to my page.

Comment: why would you have to submit your app? please read the facebook docs, submitting is only neccessary for specific permission in a login process and for putting an app in the app center.

Comment: I get an error saying: "The app specified in fb:app_id meta tag is not published yet. App attribution will be disabled when shared stories are rendered. Please check the status in the app settings." I have no idea what it means by "App attribution", but it sounds like it needs publishing.

Comment: where do you get that error? please add a screenshot to your question. either way, read my answer.

Comment: I get that error from the object debug page: http://i.imgur.com/GuPVg3S.png

Comment: you can ignore that, it´s not even an error

Answer (score 1):

You should always create an App if you want to use Social Plugins, but you don´t need to set `fb:admins` and `fb:app_id`. You can create an App here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

After that, all you need is the App ID. Just use the Like Button generator and replace the `appId` parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator

Of course you don´t need to submit your App to Facebook. That is only neccessary for specific permissions in a login process and for putting an app in the app center.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try ignoring `fb:admins` if I set a valid `fb:app_id`. I get an error saying: "The app specified in fb:app_id meta tag is not published yet. App attribution will be disabled when shared stories are rendered. Please check the status in the app settings." I have no idea what it means by "App attribution", but it sounds like it needs publishing.

Comment: remove the fb:app_id and just copy the code from the like button generator - and replace your app id in the code.

Comment: Also, how is this website attached to my page then? I want likes and shares to be connected to my page. I can't seem a way to link my page and app in Facebook.

Comment: it is not at all attached to your facebook page. why would it be attached? you can just use the url of your facebook page for your like button, that´s about it.

Comment: I think you must be wrong, I started again with like/share button code from their website and when another Facebook user presses share they get the following error: http://i.imgur.com/z4SwNiu.png

Comment: why would i be wrong? that´s a completely different topic, just put your app live in the app settings. in general, if you hit an error, always put it into google, that one is very well known and there are many stackoverflow threads about it.

Comment: Ah, I was very confused about making things live – it seemed that to make it live it had to go into review. Really not very clear! Thanks for your help.

Comment: what? no, you do NOT need to go to review just to take your app live...it´s just a simple switch in the app settings, nothing else.

Comment: "It *seemed* that to make it live it had to go into review" That was how it appeared to me when viewing the app. It turns out that as you say, you don't need to put it in review just make it live. Nowadays it's extremely common for things to have to be "reviewed" before going live, and I'd just assumed that this was true with the FB app as the live switch and review information is all on the same page. It seemed related.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to create a facebook app using developer tab that will provide you fb:app_id and fb:secret_key. You need to mention your app name and the url of your app so that facebook will authenticate your app with your fb:app_id.

Comment: I can't find any documentation that says this. Can you reference any? Also, does this app needs to be submitted for review? What about the `fb:admins`, surely that info can be accessed from the `fb:app_id`.